# How to cast Strings "1" and "0" to true and false in AS3?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, casting, boolean

In AS3 when you try to cast a String containing "1" or "0" to Boolean using Boolean() the result is true in both cases.

```
Boolean("1") // true
Boolean("0") // true
```

How would you get true in the first case and false in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check for the string to contain the exact value for "1", like this:

```
var myBool:Boolean = (myString === "1");
```

Or you could do a double casting, like this:

```
var myBool:Boolean = Boolean(int(myString));
```

The latter has the advantage of being true for strings with whitespace ("  1") or even "01" (in case this is desirable), but still "0", " 0" or "00" would be false.

I've added this Q&A here because I just stumbled into this problem of Boolean("0") being true. If you have a better solution, feel free to comment.

Comment: It happens in any ECMAScript implementation (JavaScript for instance).

Answer (score 1):

> How would you get true in the first case and false in the second case?

There are a variety of ways to convert `'1'` and `'0'` to `true` and `false` respectively, but it matters more how *other* numbers are cast for how to handle these cases.

For example, if you want to treat these strings as numbers, and cast them to boolean as though they were numbers, then you can just cast to `Number` before casting to `Boolean`:

```
var t = '1';
var f = '0';

Boolean(Number(t)); //true
!!+f; //false, terse syntax
```

This means that other non-zero numbers such as `'-1'` will become `true`, and non-numbers that convert to `NaN`, such as `'word'` will become `false`.

If instead you want to detect if the value is `'1'` exactly, and everything else should be `false`, then use a simple equality comparison:

```
t === '1'; //true
f === '1'; //false
```

If instead you want to detect if the value is *not zero*, you can use a simple inequality comparison:

```
t !== '0'; //true
f !== '0'; //false
```

In the end what matters are your expected input and their respective expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess using Boolean(Number()) would be the same as using Boolean(int()). The "terse syntax" doesn't compile in AS3 in strict mode.

Comment: @OMA Internally, Flash uses Number for all numeric types and does some extra conversion for int(), uint(), etc.